# Styling ListBox with Static Content

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, styling

I have a set of static content that I want in a `ListBox` control.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Image />
            <TextBlock Text="One" />
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Image />
            <TextBlock Text="Two" />
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Image />
            <TextBlock Text="Three" />
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

How do I go about styling this? I know I can style each `ListBoxItem` individually, and I know how to style when data bound, but how do I style the a listbox item template when using static content like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define the items as low-level objects and use data-templating, which may not be the same as styles but properties are only set once as well:

```
<ListBox xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <ListBox.Items>
        <sys:String>one</sys:String>
        <sys:String>two</sys:String>
        <sys:String>three</sys:String>
    </ListBox.Items>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- "Style" this at will -->
            <StackPanel>
                <Image />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

(*To style the wrapping ListBoxItems you can try using an implicit style defined in the `ListBox.Resources`*)

---

*The following only works in WPF*

Add a style to the resources of the ListBox and only set the `TargetType` and not the `x:Key`, it will be applied automatically.

You can even nest this automatic application using Resources, e.g.:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <!-- Items here -->
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I'm doing this on a WP7 device and apparently this format doesn't work. `x:Type` isn't a part of the schema. There is no `Style.Resources` on the `Style` node. Maybe the schema declarations for the phone are different or this way isn't supported on the phone.

Comment: Right, you probably should not tag WP7 questions with WPF since it is not the exact same, like Silverlight it represents a sub-set of WPF and those things are not possible there, it's a shame. `x:Type` is not needed by the way, you can just type the name in this case since the compiler knows that the string needs to be converted to a type, but i do not know what to do about the lack of `Style.Resources`, sorry.

Comment: I'll change the tags. I figured styling wouldn't be different.

Comment: @Josh: I just had a look at this again and added another approach, hopefully this works (i could only test it with normal Silverlight)